# Action after dismissing a UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, dismiss, uiactivityviewcontroller

How could I call an action after the UIActivityViewController is dismissed? For example, if I wanted to change a piece of text after the user dismisses the UIActivityViewController.

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use its completion handler property.

From Apple's documentation:

> completion handler
>
> The completion handler to execute after the activity view controller
>   is dismissed.
>        @property(nonatomic,copy) UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler completionHandler Discussion
>   When the user-selected service finishes operating on the data, or when
>   the user dismisses the view controller, the view controller executes
>   this completion handler to let your app know the final result of the
>   operation.
>        Availability Available in iOS 6.0 and later. Declared In UIActivityViewController.h